# Correct Sentence Construction

Tags: sentence-construction

My friend had asked me about how to go to one picnic spot which I had visited long back. I told him the route. After weekend I want to ask him whether he had gone to that picnic spot or not

How should I Ask?

> Did you go to picnic spot which you were asking me?
>   Or
>
> Had you been/gone to that picnic spot which you were asking me?
>   Or
>
> Have you been/gone to that picnic spot which you were asking me?

Comment: When you and the listener know about the same picnic spot, use the definite article *the* in the first question.

Answer (score 1):

All three *did you go*, *have you been* and *had you been* seem okay to me. However, I'll try to tell the subtlety I find.

Firstly, I'd select the verb *been* over *go*. That's because *have/had been* refers to go to a place and come back. In the context of *visiting* a place, *been* serves better than *go.* But that does not mean the first question is incorrect. A note for the first question though - when you and the listener are talking about **the same spot**, it'd take the definite article **the**.

In an informal speech, you may ask

> Did you go to *the* picnic spot (which) you were asking me?

This means you are asking whether the person ***went*** to that place.

> Had you been to that picnic spot which you were asking me?

Looks okay (using *that* instead of *the* talks about the same spot, so article is omitted). But then using *had* gives a flair of *more past* and not *recent past*.

> Have you been to that picnic spot which you were asking me?

Also looks okay. Just using *have* **here** I think talks more about the recent activity. It may seem that he has just visited the place and you are asking this. Using *have + participle* is recent as compared to *had + participle*. Compare *I had done this* over *I have done this*. The latter is recent past or at least its *effects* has remained as on the time the sentence is spoken. Good to note that in your very own question you used *"....I had  <del>have</del> visited **long back.**"* That supports it!

But as I said, all three seem *okay to me.*

Comment: I really found the note about 'been' useful. +1